# Permission Error Facebook Custom Conversion Stats

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, python-requests, facebook-business-sdk, facebook-python-business-sdk

I'm trying to get the custom conversions for a Facebook Business using the Python SDK but I can't seem to make it work.

After calling `CustomConversion.get_stats(customConversionId)` or `graph.get_object('/customConversionId/stats')` I get the following error `"(#200) Cannot access an object not managed by the business owning this app."`

I:

- Added the app in the Facebook Business
- Got a token from the GraphExplorer for the App
- Cannot see the custom conversions in the Facebook Business site
- When calling `AdAccount.get_custom_conversions(adAccountId, fields = fields)` I do get the custom conversions, but only with the provided fields

I also tried to create a system user and give him permission to the business following these steps. 
I'm running out of ideas and I don't know what I'm missing.

I've found little documentation that didn't help much on this.

Thoughts on what I should do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to go into your business manager setting and add the app.

[image]

I hope this could help you